# Prepare_targets Function takes too long to execute

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to run machine learning algorithm on 1GB csv file . At a cell in code it is now taking over 2 hours running and didn't finish yet I wonder if there is a way

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(precision=3, suppress=True)
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental import preprocessing
import io



data = pd.read_csv('./Final2.csv',  header=None)# retrieve numpy array
dataset = data.values
#data_features=data.copy()
...
# split into input (X) and output (y) variables
X = dataset[:, :-1]
y = dataset[:,-1]



X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=2)


# prepare input data
def prepare_inputs(X_train, X_test):
    oe = OrdinalEncoder()
    oe.fit(X_train)
    X_train_enc = oe.transform(X_train)
    X_test_enc = oe.transform(X_test)
    return X_train_enc, X_test_enc

# prepare target
def prepare_targets(y_train, y_test):
    le = LabelEncoder()
    le.fit(y_train)
    y_train_enc = le.transform(y_train)
    y_test_enc = le.transform(y_test)
    return y_train_enc, y_test_enc
```

**Then here it takes a very long time to execute :**

```
# prepare input data
X_train_enc, X_test_enc = prepare_inputs(X_train, X_test)
# prepare output data
y_train_enc, y_test_enc = prepare_targets(y_train, y_test)
```

Comment: You could try to add the decorator `@lru_cache` from the module `functools` module. It usually improves performance. Simply import the `lru_cache`decorator wrapper function from `functools` and add the decorator in the line right before the definition of those functions.